# Certain computers display compatibility view

Tags: php, internet-explorer, compatibility-mode

I know that this question had been asked everywhere but I just can't get the solution even after trying the suggested ways.

So my client's IE automatically switched to compatibility view while viewing the website and the navigation is not displaying inline, certain words just overlapped but when I use my computer and my colleague's, they display normally.

I tried adding:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7,IE=8,IE=9"/>
```

And when I tried to view in compatibility view IE9, it is still the same.

Any idea on how to force compatibility view to display the same as standard view?

Thank you!

Comment: Make sure it has a doctype.

Comment: Yes it has. I am currently using X-Cart to program the website. However, when I was looking through the IE debug console, it show !doctype as <!-- DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd" -->

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be best going with the `edge` content option. It will force IE to not display the compatibility mode button

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

Much deeper answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6771584/109711)

Comment: So does that mean if as long as the user don't manually change it using debug console, there will be no way for them to change to compatibility mode?

Comment: Yes, that's my understanding of it. Just try it and find out!

Comment: Okay thank you :D Will accept once my client confirm with me!

Comment: Hi! Sorry to ask a question in here. I had made it IE=edge but apparently it goes crazy when using IE 10. Is there a way to ask it IE=9 when users using IE10 and IE=edge when they are using IE9 or older?